# Proof of the minimum rank-deficient of a r-rank matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Proof of Theorem 2.5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhDfJ.png)

Reference : Golub G.H., Van Loan C.F.- Matrix Computations book.

I fail to understand the last line of the proof as to why,

$$||A-B||^2_2 \geq ||(A-B)z||^2_2 $$
I fail to understand how $z$ is so special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,
$$\|A-B\|_2=\max\{\|(A-B)z\|_2:\|z\|\leq1\}. $$
Thus, for any $z\in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|z\|_2\leq 1$, we have
$$ \|(A-B)z\|_2\leq\|A-B\|_2, $$
and squaring both sides of the inequality gives the resulting inequality.

Comment: @Awygan Thanks for the explanation, but $z$ is the 2-norm vector in the intersection. I don't think $z \in R^n$ but it only belongs in the intersection subspace.

Comment: @learner I don't understand. If $z$ is an element of a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ then $z\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ Awygan I believe the intersection of subspace, i.e. $z \in$ span($x_1, x_2, ... x_k$) $\cap$ span($v_1, v_2, .. $) which is a subset of $R^n$ and not the entire space $R^n$.

Comment: @learner the intersection of subspaces is again a subspace, so it contains a unit vector.

Comment: @ Awygan I believe the intersection of subspace, i.e. $z \in$ span($x_1, x_2, ... x_k$) $\cap$ span($v_1, v_2, .. $) which is a subset of $R^n$ and not the entire space $R^n$. Sorry for re-commenting. I had to edit the last comment. Have I understood $z$ wrong ?

Comment: @learner The set $\text{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-k})\cap\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+1})$ is a **nontrivial subspace** of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means it contains a $2$-norm unit vector.